# How to know the SmtpServer settings for my Office 365 provided Outlook 2016 installation?

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, office365, outlook-2016

I'm trying to use the `Send-MailMessage` commandlet in Powershell. It requires that I tell is my SMTP server settings.

I am running an Outlook 2016 desktop client that is associated with my Office 365 subscription. How do I get to know the Smtp server settings?

I tried **File -> Account Settings** but that doesn't show me the server url and the port number.

Comment: https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/options/popandimap  That's to get your smtp settings... If you want to send email, you just need theses. If the real interest lies in grabbing those informations from outlook client, I am not familiar enough with the outlook interop to be of much use there.

Answer (score 0):

If your mail is hosted by Office365, then it will have the same SMTP settings...

```
Server: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587 or 25
TLS: Enabled

Send-MailMessage -To <email> -Cc <email> -Attachments <path> -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" -Credential $mycreds -UseSsl -Port "587"
```

[link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4)